# A build only device cannot be used to run this target

Tags: ios, xcode

I get this error when I trying to test an app.

**A build only device cannot be used to run this target.**

No supported iOS devices are available. Connect a device to run your application or choose a simulated device as the destination.

Comment: If you use a device and you have your apple developer account, please delete the app from your device, and then run it.

Answer (score 81):

add `-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.3'` to your `xcodebuild`

Comment: Explanation: Xcode tries to build with the Generic iOS Device but the test have to be build at the simulator.

Comment: A complete and working command: `xcodebuild test -project YourProject.xcodeproj -scheme YourProject -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.3'`

Comment: /usr/bin/xcodebuild is a binary file. You should probably not modify it.

Comment: Why do you want to modify it?

Comment: You don't need to add this into `xcodebuild`.
All you need is to run this command with parameters

Answer (score 62):

Maybe the Scheme has switched to a Generic device. Try to choose again the connected device from the Scheme menu:

[image: Menu image]

Answer (score 27):

Below is my way

Select project -> General -> Deployment Info -> Deployment Target -> choose a lower version 
[image]

Comment: This case is useful when you import a project with deployment target higher than your local deployment target, lowering it can resolve the issue

Answer (score 11):

You need to get a list of valid destinations. To do this, specify an erroneous key-value pair and xcodebuild will spit out the combinations that work:

**List Destinations Command**

```
xcodebuild test -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator' -workspace Register.xcworkspace -scheme ThatTestTarget
```

**Output Example**

```
Available destinations for the "ThatTestTarget" scheme:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:145A9B7E-B336-4819-8059-2FFEC408E05E, OS:11.1, name:iPad (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:69ABAF6F-ADA3-4E38-AC97-D71001447663, OS:9.3, name:iPad 2 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:550E2F18-406D-4586-84BB-E48F1D704F27, OS:10.3.1, name:iPad Air }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:94734F1C-775F-40FA-9015-8196C08805EF, OS:11.1, name:iPad Air }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1DB953DD-CD97-4EC7-8006-BCF01DF3E63F, OS:11.1, name:iPad Air 2 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DE3072DA-2E31-423D-9D77-220626F8B90A, OS:11.1, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3B5D18DB-13B5-4F28-B654-7D2ECDD1F6F0, OS:11.1, name:iPad Pro (10.5-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A4225E3A-512C-4F42-ADD9-1E7E448C4D27, OS:11.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:684FF1BA-8784-4B7C-B4E5-5231772F0FAC, OS:11.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation) }
```

**Change Colons for Equals Signs, Remove Spaces, Ignore the ID**

So if you want to use this destination:

```
platform:iOS Simulator, id:684FF1BA-8784-4B7C-B4E5-5231772F0FAC, OS:11.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)
```

Change the colons for commas, remove the spaces, remove the ID, so you get this string:

```
platform=iOS Simulator,OS=11.1,name=iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)
```

Then the entire command would be:

```
xcodebuild test -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=11.1,name=iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)' -workspace Register.xcworkspace -scheme ThatTestTarget
```

Answer (score 9):

i meet a problem that only "Generic iOS Device" can be choosed.
and when i  run ,it says 
"A build only device cannot be used to run this target.No supported iOS devices are available. Connect a device to run your application or choose a simulated device as the destination "

and my solution for the problem is selecting Build Settings ---> Deployment ----->IOS Deployment Target---->choose a lower version like 8.0,

and i found  the simulator come out and can be chosen.

Comment: Do you have simulators with newer OS version installed? Goto Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads to see the list of compatible legacy simulator runtimes.

Answer (score 5):

You are building for Xcode's "Build Only Device", which is compiling the app. for the ARM processor (whereas compiling for the simulator targets the Intel CPU on your Mac.)

Plug in a device and select it from the active scheme popup, or, select one of the simulators and you should be good to go.

Comment: I don't call myself a rook because I'm good at this stuff... Thank you 2 hours wasted ha....

Answer (score 4):

With XCode 8.3.2 I had this error message after I tried to run the app on a locked device. I unlocked and reattached as requested but the "A build only device cannot be used to run this target." message appeared.

I simply changed the target to a simulator and changed it back - it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same error message. Here's what I have experienced and did so far;

> **Step 1: Check your target.**
>
> My current target is IOS 13.2. From here, you will not see what
> versions you currently have on your machine.

[image]

> **Step 2: Check available versions on your local**
>
> - Click the **Generic IOS Device**

[image]

> - This will display a dropdown menu that contains a **Download Simulators...** selection
> - In case the **Download Simulators...** selection is not visible, you need to lower down your target. In my case, from 13.2 I made it 13.0 (This depends on your current XCode) then repeat the **Step 2** again
> - From here, I can now see the **Download Simulators...** selection
> - Select it

[image]

> - You will now see what are the available versions you have
> - From here, you may choose to download or just use the version you have (The one that is selected)

[image]

> **Step 3: Change your IOS target accordingly**
>
> - Now that you already know what are the available versions of the simulator you have locally, you can now change the IOS target.
> - In my case I choose to use IOS 11 (Just for this sample)
> - Then I change the target

[image]

> - Again click the **Generic IOS Device**

[image]

> - From here, you can now select any simulator under that IOS

[image]

I am not an expert, I just wanted to share my experience and I hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, if you get the error `A build only device cannot be used to run this target`, and see in the Issue navigator this text:

> ProjectName
>   Target Integrity:
>   iOS Deployment Target 'XX.X' is
>   newer than SDK 'iOS YY.Y' in
>   target ProjectName

then the issue is that the project requires an iOS SDK that is newer than what your version of Xcode has available. You'll find this issue in, say, projects taking advantage of new/beta iOS SDK functionalities such as ARKit.

The solution is to download the [newest beta version of Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/), which should have support for the non-public released iOS SDK that the application requires. If you have the latest Xcode, try finding the target iOS in `Preferences -> Components -> Simulators`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using cordova/Ionic Go to Products -> Destination-> Choose the target and re run

Answer (score 2):

Modification to @Quver's answer. With latest Xcode version(8.3), the parameters to destination command should be given in double quotes. Single quotes didn't work for me

add `-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7"` to your `xcodebuild`

I haven't mentioned OS version in above command because when a newer version of iOS is released, this command will through error telling that this device is not found. So it is better not to give OS version

Answer (score 2):

In my case this happened, when I selected a Generic iOS device and tried to "build" in order to publish it to the AppStore.
But I should have selected Product -> Archive instead

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue for emulator,

Firstly check your emulator list

> Window > Devices and Simulators

after choose any device and click check OS Version

If you have only Apple Watch OS, You should download new IOS Simulator

and click download more simulator runtimes..

choose your correct IOS Simulator and download it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after updating to latest MacOS version Ventura and Xcode  version.

You have to [Enable developper mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device) again manually.

> As indicated by the alert, to enable Developer Mode go to Settings >
> Privacy & Security on the iOS device. Scroll down to the Developer
> Mode list item and navigate into it. To toggle Developer mode, use the
> “Developer Mode” switch.

[image: Enable developper mode in settings]

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

1. I applied for a new AppleID and added it to the "Xcode->Preferences->Account" to solve this problem. (Xcode 7.3)
2. At the same time I deleted original AppleID in the "Xcode->Preferences->Account",because it was no longer a paid account and couldn't add new devices.

Answer (score 0):

xcodebuild things were not working in my case.

Here's what I've solved.

I've removed my apple account and re-set(login) on the xcode preference,
and this was solved.

ps. on iphone 10.1, I needed to push Trust button on General > Device Management > account info > Trust App

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by going to the project settings, and under my 'Targets' section I had to set the Tests target to the correct team.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to get the list of available **destinations** then call xcodebuild and pass in the command line option `-showdestinations`, and it will print valid options for you to pick from:

```
xcodebuild -showdestinations -workspace Register.xcworkspace -scheme ThatTestTarget
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost anything above, including restarting XCode, none of them worked for me. I solved this problem by simply **restarting my Mac**. Yes, the classic solution.

A side note: This problem occurred to my XCode after it requested my Mac password from me, probably after an automatic upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

For xcode v11:

I ran into this issue when trying to create an Archive of my project. I was trying to click "Build" when the device was set to "Generic iOS Device", but the proper steps were:

1. Set device to "Generic iOS Device"
2. Go to Product -> Archive (**skip pressing Build!**)

Answer (score 0):

I am learning Tauri Mobile development and just ran into this issue. My problem is that I didn't have an available iOS Simulator.
Open the "Simulator" app from Launchpad, "File" -> "New Simulator..." , then create a new simulator. And select the simulator you just created in Xcode and it will run!

Answer (score 0):

After 8 years still a valid question. I opened an old project to compile it for Apple Silicon, but I got this message and I could not even select a destination except Rosetta. Finally I found hidden under the **PROJECT** settings (not TARGETS) a user defined entry of **Valid_Architecture**. No matter what I entered still no success, but selecting the line (see image) and Edit/Delete was solving the issue. [Ancient obsolete user defined setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg5aX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** If you see "A build only device cannot be used to run this target" when you select only "Any IOS Device"

**Solution :**
YOU DO NOT NEED TO RUN THE APPLICATION DIRECTLY TO ARCHIVE IT!!

My problem is that I used "Start active schema" when I had to click on "Product > Archive", then the code runs and builds the project to put it directly in "App Store Connect"!

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

You are trying to run on a device when you already built it for a different scheme.
Go to

> Product > Clean.

Then build with your device chosen from the active schemes.

Comment: I upgraded my Xcode to 15.0 and ran into this error. I did `Product -> Clean Build Folder`, and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had an entirely different problem. For some reason my app "**Devices**" was set to **Universal** build as opposed to **iPhone**. When I switched it to iPhone everything worked. Didn't need any extra settings.