# xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace. Reason: A build only device cannot be used to run this target

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, xcodebuild

I'm trying to build and test on device (iPhone) using command line:

```
xcodebuild  \
    -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace \
    -scheme MyApp \
    -destination 'generic/platform=iOS,id=iPhoneUUID' \
    clean test
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace MyApp with scheme MyApp.
    Reason: A build only device cannot be used to run this target.
```

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error?

I'll really appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36463590/1724845)

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: @SvenDriemecker, yes, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut off the `generic` part in your `-destination` value. Else Xcode won't try to build for your device, but for the generic build only device:

```
xcodebuild  \
    -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace \
    -scheme MyApp \
    -destination 'platform=iOS,id=iPhoneUUID' \
    clean test
```